# How to pass class reference (not object) using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a scenario where there are multiple Activities and a Service. 
All this Activities when need to get data from any URL, starts the Service (activity's `class name` is passed in Intent) and register a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen to `responseIntent` which will be sent by Service on getting the response. `Service` will pass the `class name` back in Intent along with response.

I have implemented this and it works. But the doubt is that from `BroadcastReceiver`'s  `onReceive()` method, how can I call a method of an activity which received a broadcast event?

**Note :** I want to deal with class reference but not an object. I tried this,

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Class<?> thisActivity = Class.forName(intent.getStringExtra("ClassName"));
    thisActivity.hello();  // hello() is a public and static method
}
```

But it does not work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an object reference through an `Intent`. Imagine that `Parcelable` objects are just like `Serializable`objects, their references are lost.

You should declare your `BroadcastReceiver` as an inner-class in your `Activity`, and then you will have a reference to the enclosing `Activity`. This is the way to do it.

Comment: I have already done that way but it introduces a lot of redundancies as I have to define `BroadcastReceiver` in all the activities with almost same code in `onReceive()` method.

Comment: than make an `abstract` or "BaseActivity" in which you encapsulate all the common behaviour, and let the others extend that "BaseActivity"

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not supported in android/java.

Comment: Then who will extend `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: as I have mentioned in the answer... you will create an inner class for the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the full package name to the 'ClassName' string, like this:

```
Class<?> thisActivity = Class.forName(intent.getStringExtra("com.android.youapp.ClassName"));
```

Note: if this class resides in a different library project you should set the string name accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How did you get your class name, which you are trying to extract from Intent's "ClassName"?

Preparing intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(....);
String className = MyClass.class.getCanonicalName();
i.putExtra(CLASS_NAME, className);
```

Extracting intent content:

```
String canName = intent.getStringExtra(CLASS_NAME);
mClientClass = Class.forName(canName);
java.lang.reflect.Methodm m = mClientClass.getMethod("hello", new Class[] {});
```

Getting result:

```
Object result = m.invoke(mClientClass, new Object[] {});
```